# How to pass an argument to a TypeScript module?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to pass a variable to TypeScript modules?

When using a class, we can pass arguments to the constructor:

```
class validator {
    constructor(public regex: RegExp) { }
    ok = (s: string) => this.regex.test(s);
}
```

But, how can I pass the same argument to a module?

```
module validator {
    var regex = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    export var ok = (s: string) => regex.test(s);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export the variable you want to modify:

```
module validator {
    export var regex = /^[A-Za-z]+$/; // <-- export var
    export var ok = (s: string) => regex.test(s);
};

validator.regex = /.*$/;
```

This will make module behave similar to a static class: you have a single point of access to this variable.

Comment: can i have multiple instances of a module ?

Comment: No, you can use classes if you need multiple instances.